# Faster way to search through many files using a set of given strings

Tags: linux, shell-script

How do I grep a given set of numbers/Strings in a directory containing many files(each one sizing over 1gb) . And also I want it to be fast. Below is my script but it is very slow:

```
 #!/bin/sh

echo "Report Key|Status|FileName"
SERVICE1="/dir1/dir2/file.csv"
FINDCMD1='"sting1":"'
FINDCMD2='"'
for i in $(cat $SERVICE1);

do
#echo "$i"
FINALFINDCMD=$FINDCMD1$i$FINDCMD2
ORACLEFINALFIND=$ORACLEFINDCMD$i$FINDCMD2
SERVICE2=$(cd /dir1/dir2 && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -n1000 -r0P3 grep $FINALFINDCMD| grep "string2")
if [[ $SERVICE2 = *"string2"* ]]; then
SERVICE3=$(echo $SERVICE2 | cut -c73-115)
        echo "$i|report found|$SERVICE3"
fi
else
    echo "$i|report not found"
fi
  let i++
done
```

Suppose: file.csv has the following numbers:

```
123456
234567
345678
```

The script takes in these reports individually and greps them in the files in dir2(refer SERVICE2 in the above code). And then prints if the numbers/reports were found or not. If they were, it prints in which file the number was found.

Comment: What in the shell pitfalls is going on here?  Can you provide a sample input/output?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @Jesse_b. Thank you for your quick response. I have edited the question to help you understand better.

Comment: You might be interested in this: [Fastest possible grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066609/fastest-possible-grep)

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -f /dir1/dir2/file.csv /dir1/dir2/*
```

This will pull patterns from your `.csv` file and search for them in the files located in `/dir1/dir2`.  I suggest not having your .csv in the same directory you want to search otherwise it's going to be a match. If you want to search recursively within `dir2` add the `-r` flag to grep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grep a pattern in all files of a directory. You can do it with grep command itself.

example:

`grep -Hnr "pattern" folderPath`

Let me know if this is what your looking for.

Comment: Hi @SivaPrasath. The above grep function is not working. Ia mgetting the following output when I run:
`147815|report found|/dirx/diry| grep "String2`

It is not grepping the number. And the string 2 is also half printed